# Multiple of 2 element based on certain condition

Tags: xquery

I am trying to calculate a value and display in one of the element. This value should be a multiple of 2 values based on certain condition. Like as shown in below example where for unbounded structure of **ConsumptionPerRecord**,

we have a element **Consumption**. This variable should be determine as on SizeType and Count.

- if SizeType is A then value in Consumption should be 0.5 x Count(say 2) = 1
- if SizeType is B then value in Consumption should be 1.0 x Count(say 2) = 3

Note - value in SizeType is a predefined list of Values ( like A, B and C) and count can be any numeric value(1,2,3,4)... 
now the consumption value should be ..

- if SizeType is A then value in Consumption should be **0.5**( a constant which represent SizeType A) x Count(say 2) = 1
- if SizeType is B then value in Consumption should be 1.0 x Count(say 2) = 3

So on..

I looked for example over google but could not find any such transformation through XQuery.

```
     <ns0:Consumption>should be .5 * count variable</ns0:Consumption>



<ns0:Response xmlns:ns0="http://testV4">
<ns0:ReferenceData>Dummy Client reference</ns0:ReferenceData>
<ns0:DataDetails>
<ns0:Status>Not Available</ns0:Status>
<ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
     <ns0:SizeType>A</ns0:SizeType>
     <ns0:Count>2</ns0:Count>
     <ns0:Consumption>should be .5 * count variable</ns0:Consumption>
     <ns0:NotConsumed>5</ns0:NotConsumed>
</ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
<ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>
     <ns0:SizeType>B</ns0:SizeType>
     <ns0:Count>2</ns0:Count>
     <ns0:Consumption>0</ns0:Consumption>
     <ns0:NotConsumed>2</ns0:NotConsumed>
</ns0:ConsumptionPerRecord>

<ns0:Message>Success</ns0:Message>
<ns0:StatusCode>1000</ns0:StatusCode>
</ns0:Response>
```

Comment: I don't get what you want, could you please review your question and try to improve the language. Where does this multiplication factor for SizeType A or B come from? If it is static, what is the value for SizeType C? Please clarify what your expected output is and also show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Hi @dirkk - I did tried modifying the question.  eventualy my objective here is a multiply 2 element value and then display in third one.

Comment: I guess I got the answer and testing same in my environment.  A simple expression like below will help. {sum($EquipmentCount * 2)}